# A question from 1989 leningrad mathematical olympiad

Tags: abstract-algebra, contest-math, binary-operations

Prove that we cannot define an binary operation $*$ on the set of integers Z satisfy all of the three properties below simultaneously:

For any $A∈Z,B∈Z,C∈Z:$

1.$A*B=-(B*A)$

2.$(A*B)*C=A*(B*C)$ (Associative Law)

3.For every $A\in Z$ there exist $B∈Z,C∈Z$ such that $A=B*C$

I have got stucked for three days on this questions.Anyway,I will show some result and idea I had:

1.for any X∈Z,we have $X*X=-(X*X)$.So we have $X*X=0$

2.for any X∈Z,we have $X*0=-(0*X)=X*(X*X)=(X*X)*X=0*X$.So we have $X*0=0*X=0$

3.Now For any $X∈Z$($X≠0$).We define the orbit of X--$Ox$ to be the set $Ox$={S|$∃Y∈Z$ such that $X*Y=S$},and the stabilizer of X--$Fx$ to be the set $Fx$={T|$T*X=X*T=0$}.

My goal is to prove that actually $Ox=Fx$.And therefore since $X∈Fx$,so $X∈Ox$,and we reach a contradiction since $X∉Ox$(otherwise if $∃Y∈Z$ such that $X*Y=X$,then $(X*Y)*Y=X*(Y*Y)=X*0=X*Y=X=0$)

It is easy to see that $Ox⊆Fx$,since for any $S∈Ox$,we have $X*S=X*(X*Y)=(X*X)*Y=0*Y=0$,so $S∈Fx$

However,for the other direction,I cannot deduce out,which I need help.

I think the backgroud of this question is the orbit&stabilizer theorem in the course abstract algebra.So I have a strong intuition that I am on the right track.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Does $AB$ mean $A\star B$?  If so, how can you deduce, say, that $X\star X=-X\star X\implies X\star X=0$?  All we know is that $X\star X=(-1\star X)\star X$.  If $AB$ doesn't mean $A\star B$ I think you need to clarify when you are using the new operation and when you are using ordinary multiplication.

Comment: @AndrewArmstrong So you mean they are *all* supposed to be the new operaton?  That there is no ordinary multiplication involved in any of these laws?

Comment: In that case, do you agree with me that it is not obvious that $X\star X=-X\star X\implies X\star X=0$?  At least that requires a proper proof.  [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), by the way, is a good tutorial on formatting for this site.  I am using "\star" to get $\star$).

Comment: To be clear:  I am guessing that "anti-commutativity" is meant to mean $A\star B=-1\star A\star B$ where the placement of the parenthesis is irrelevant (thanks to associativity), though of course I could be guessing wrong.  But, really, I think the whole thing needs a lot of clarification.

Comment: @AndrewArmstrong Sure!  Can you please edit the rest of your post likewise? Thanks! I also took out the 'typical' from the title of your question, by the way ... that was not a good use of the word here. Did you mean to say that it is a 'strange' or 'difficult' question?

Comment: @AndrewArmstrong Hmm,  but can you a least place $ signs around all your mathematical expressions? That will do a lot already!

Comment: @lulu Why can't we conclude $X\star X=0$ if it equals its negative? $X\star X$ is an integer and negation hasn't changed.

Comment: @JohnDouma  Well, you are guessing that the OP means that $-1$ is multiplying through in the ordinary way while I was guessing that the OP meant to use $\star$ there as well.  But guessing is a waste of time...the thing should be clarified.

Comment: @lulu In his first requirement he has parentheses around the product so $X\star X=-(X\star X)$. In ordinary integer arithmetic I interpret $-X$ as the additive inverse of $X$ and it is a thing to prove that $-X=(-1)*X$,.i.e. the additive inverse of an integer is the additive inverse of $1$ times the integer.

Comment: @lulu I believe you are correct about this because even if $X=-X$ we cannot conclude that $X=0$ because we don't know if the integers are still an integral domain under this product.

Comment: @JohnDouma  if $-A$ is intended to denote the additive inverse of the integer $A$ in the usual sense, then $A=-A$ does indeed imply that $A=0$.  And it is entirely possible that this is what is intended.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Note the associativity condition implies that parentheses are redundant, so something like $a \star b \star c \star d$ is uniquely-defined without parentheses.

Observe that, by axiom $3$, $1 = c \star d$ for some $c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$. A repeated application of axiom $3$ gives us that $d= e \star f$ for some integers $e,f$.

Hence we get that $1 = c \star e \star f$. Observe now that $-1 = f \star c \star e$ by the first axiom. A repeated application of the first axiom gives that $1 = e \star f \star c$. A third application gives $-1 = c \star e \star f$. But this is a contradiction, since we know that $1 = c \star e \star f$.

Comment: More generally, in any abstract algebra with binary $ \star $ and unary $ - $ satisfying the 3 properties in the question, $ - $ must be the identity. This can be proven by supposing $x ≠ -x$ for some $x$ and deriving a contradiction  as above.